# Windows Service - Additional Tab Properties

Tags: c#, windows-services

Quick question, does anybody know if it is possible to extend the windows service properties.

I want to add a new tab to create properties for my service.

Current tabs:

- General
- Log On
- Recovery
- Dependencies

I would like to add a custom tab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Windows SNMP service has some extra tabs which indicate that it is doable. Question is how they do it.